# DNS request has status: SERVFAIL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bind

Can you please take a look at the below config and what I am doing wrong?

Just set up Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with bind and when I do a dig to my server I get a status: SERVFAIL

My configuration is the below:

```
dig @192.168.6.1 www.example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.6-P2 <<>> @192.168.6.1 www.example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 25376
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.com.                        IN      A

;; Query time: 5 msec
 ;; SERVER: 192.168.6.1#53(192.168.6.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 10 12:13:28 UTC 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

named.conf.local contains

```
 zone "example.com" {
         type master;
         file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
    };

 zone "128.10.in-addr.arpa" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/db.192.168";  # 192.168.0.0/16 subnet
  };
```

the named.conf.options

```
options {
      directory "/var/cache/bind";
    recursion yes;                 # enables resursive queries
    allow-recursion { any; };  # allows recursive queries from "trusted" clients
    listen-on { 192.168.6.1; };   # ns1 private IP address - listen on private
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-query { any; };
    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
    };
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
  };
```

the db file

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
 @       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. root.example.com. (
                          1         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
  ; name server NS records
    IN      NS      ns.example.com.

  ; name servers A reconds

   ns.example.com.  IN      A       192.168.6.1

  ; A records

   www     IN      A       192.168.1.21
```

Comment: What do your nameserver logs say?

Comment: nothing actually. I checked /var/log/syslog. The last messages for named is when I restarted bind.

Jun 10 14:10:21 Server-1 named[32702]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953
Jun 10 14:10:21 Server-1 named[32702]: the working directory is not writable
Jun 10 14:10:21 Server-1 named[32702]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 0
Jun 10 14:10:21 Server-1 named[32702]: all zones loaded
Jun 10 14:10:21 Server-1 named[32702]: running

Comment: While this could simply be a question formatting issue, your zone file appears to have unnecessary leading whitespace. Leading whitespace means "use the same name as the previous record", which would create a few syntax errors in this case. I suggest using the `named-checkzone` command to validate this zonefile, but I would have expected this to appear in your logs.

Comment: Please don't post log output in a comment - instead, click on the "edit" link and add it to the question.

Comment: You should increase the log level for named and re-try the query, and then add the resulting output.

Comment: I think there is an $ORIGIN missing in your zonefile: $ORIGIN . <linebreak> $TTL 86400  ; 1 day <linebreak>
example.com       IN SOA ...

Comment: And remember to increment your serial between restarts, if you changed the zonefile by hand.

Answer (score -2):

The mistake is find in this line:
 @       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. root.example.com.
Don't use the above but rather use :
 @       IN      SOA     *example.com.* root.example.com.

Comment: That's incorrect, it should be the primary master name server so in this case it is set correctly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_record

Comment: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt also states that the first and second parameters are MNAME (The <domain-name> of the name server that was the original or primary source of data for this zone.) and RNAME (A <domain-name> which specifies the mailbox of the person responsible for this zone.). Please consider removing your answer, as it is incorrect.